# testing blob urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blob

I'm using the `Window.URL.createObjectURL` function to generate a blob url for a local video file, which I then use to set the source of a `<video>` element. This loads the video when the URL is first constructed, and everything works well. But when the web page is reloaded, the generated URL is no longer valid -- the browser automatically revokes the generated URL.

My question: Is there a way to determine if this Blob URL has actually been revoked? In other words, how do I determine if I can still use this Blob url using javascript, jquery, or whatever options are out there?

Comment: can you mention the code to generate blob url for a local video file? I am facing hard time to understand the API. If you can provide the steps, it would be highly beneficial for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution, which works... albeit, probably isn't ideal.

Basically, I take the url, set the `<video>` src to that url, and then attach a jquery `error` event handler to it. If the `error` event is called (which it is, if the blob url has been revoked) I then prompt the user to reselect their video file.